# Converting Wordpress Longtext values to valid date

Tags: php, mysql, date, type-conversion

I am new wordpress. and working in Wordpress,PHP And MYSQL. I have a database table in which all the voucher expiry dates are saved in longtext format like this:

```
       meta_id  post_id     meta_key        meta_value
        446     405     _end_time           1362483186
        460     411     _end_time       1363046400
        474     413     _end_time       1362787200
        488     418     _end_time       1363392000
        503     420     _end_time       1363219200
```

Is there anyway I could convert meta_values from Longtext to Date so that I could compare it with the user input (Date)? Please advise.

Comment: It's a `UNIX time-stamp`. You can convert it using [**date**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

Comment: @Rikesh.Thanks Rikesh.What format i will need to use for it? i mean any example?Sorry i new bee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your longtext format is a timestamp, use [date](http://www.php.net/manual/function.date.php) to transform it as a String :

```
$timestamp = 1362483186;
echo date('m d Y', $timestamp);
//With 1362483186 it'll give 03 05 2013 (month day year)
//See the php docs for more format types
```

See also the [time](http://www.php.net/manual/function.time.php) function if you need to compare to the actual time.

Comment: Thanks.That one worked for me.But how can i check whether it a Datetime or a simple date?is there anyway as i just don't want to discard the time value that comes with it?Please advise

Comment: I do not understand your question, from a timestamp you can retrieve time too. Try : `echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', $timestamp)`

Comment: @soyuka.Thanks.I have got my answer.Cheers :)